Focus isn't regained when swiping back from a Route, unlike using the back button in Flutter, iOS
Any ideas on why this is happening and possible solutions would be really welcome!
When I have assigned Focus to a Widget and I am navigating to a new route, and then navigating back to the previous route, that Widget does not re-gain Focus. That is explicitly happening when using the swiping back gesture in iOS. Back button for example has no issue in allowing the widget to re-gain focus .

You can request a function in the screen you are navigating. Then in the next screen use that function in dispose method. In the first screen focus the necessary widget inside the function.
For example:
Navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(_)=>SecondScreen(onDispose:(){
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
})));

Second screen:
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget{
final void Function() onDispose;
const SecondScreen(this.onDispose());
State<_SecondScreen> createState()=> _SecondState();
}

class _SecondState extends State<_SecondScreen>{

@override
dispose(){
widget.onDispose();
super.dispose();
  }
}


hey, thank you for your kind intention of helping me out here!
Is this issue normal though for iOS or should I be looking for other culprits?
Much appreciated .

I think it's a bug from the flutter side, so I don't know whether it's normal issue or not. I'm glad if this helped you. I would be happy if you check this as a solution
